# checkboxes for wxtreectrl in wxformbuilder

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

In `wxTreeListCtrl` we have `wxTL_CHECKBOX`, but it selects only one item and not all children of that item. Can we have checkbox feature for `wxTreeListCtrl` which will select all children of subtree when that parent node is selected? Or do we have such similar feature for any other tree component? I need to build a tree structure where, if we select any one node then all its children nodes should be selected. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all children of an item when it is checked, you have to do if yourself by calling `CheckItemRecursively()` method from your `wxEVT_TREELIST_ITEM_CHECKED` handler.

Comment: yup, thank you so much :) I am planning to use CheckItemRecursively() to mark children as selected or unselected, i.e. I need to call this function every time any node is selected or unselected. Can you tell me exactly from where I can call this function. I mean which function is executed in cpp code after we select checkbox from GUI?

Comment: I checked event types and macros from treelist.h, but I am not getting from where should I call CheckItemRecursively().

Comment: Oops, yes, I forgot about `CheckItemRecursively()`, so it's even simpler than that. You just need to call it from the `ITEM_CHECKED` event handler, see the updated answer.

Comment: yup, Thank you :)